# CSS3 image masking, photoshop style. Is it possible?

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is go beyond simple image masking (nothing to do with text image masking). I know about canvas masking a vector shape, and rectangle clipping, but what if we want to use a black and white opacity map like a photoshop mask. Is it possible with html5 / css3? Is there a way to do it with canvas tag that I just haven't realized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a few ways to mask an image right now. Webkit has -webkit-mask, while in Firefox, Mozilla prefers you to use an SVG mask to mask an image.

Here is an article on [canvas masking](http://www.benbarnett.net/2011/06/02/using-html5-canvas-for-image-masks/)